# After successful execution of vorpal command error is thrown

Tags: node.js, vorpal.js

I have add the following vorpal command.

```
vorpal
    .command('connect [username] [password]')
    .description('Connect to server.')
    .action(function (args, callback) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            // deleting options key from args
            delete args.options;

        var context = domain.create();

        // error handling in domain
        context.on('error', errorHandler);

        // running the connect in domain
        context.run(function() {
            console.log("Arguments : ", args);
        });
    }, 0);
});

vorpal.delimiter('hdb$').show();
```

Following is the stack trace as it is generated in side the vorpal library only.

```
Vorpal Prompt error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'setRawMode' of null
at ReadStream.setRawMode (tty.js:67:15)
at Interface._setRawMode (readline.js:177:23)
at new Interface (readline.js:137:10)
at Object.exports.createInterface (readline.js:39:10)
at Object.Interface.createInterface (/home/users/my-cli/node_modules/vorpal/node_modules/inquirer/node_modules/readline2/index.js:34:21)
at module.exports (/home/users/my-cli/node_modules/vorpal/node_modules/inquirer/lib/ui/baseUI.js:14:30)
at new module.exports (/home/users/my-cli/node_modules/vorpal/node_modules/inquirer/lib/ui/prompt.js:15:8)
at Object.promptModule as prompt
at Object.ui.prompt (/home/users/my-cli/node_modules/vorpal/lib/ui.js:171:25)
at EventEmitter.vorpal._prompt (/home/users/my-cli/node_modules/vorpal/lib/vorpal.js:528:15)
at EventEmitter. (/home/users/my-cli/node_modules/vorpal/lib/vorpal.js:542:12)
at callback (/home/users/my-cli/node_modules/vorpal/lib/vorpal.js:705:22)
at /home/users/my-cli/node_modules/vorpal/lib/vorpal.js:824:7
at EventEmitter._commandSetCallback (/home/users/my-cli/node_modules/vorpal/lib/session.js:455:5)
at EventEmitter.session.completeCommand (/home/users/my-cli/node_modules/vorpal/lib/session.js:519:12)
at onCompletion (/home/users/my-cli/node_modules/vorpal/lib/session.js:465:10)
```

Please let me know if I am doing something wrong in this.

Answer (score 1):

I think this may simply be because you aren't running the callback after the command completes:

```
var vorpal = require('vorpal')();

vorpal
    .command('connect [username] [password]')
    .description('Connect to server.')
    .action(function (args, callback) {
      setTimeout(function(){
        // ... your logic
        callback();
      }, 0)
    });

vorpal.delimiter('hdb$').show();
```

The above works - start with the above logic, and  then start adding in your logic. If it breaks again even with the callback, back track on a process of elimination to find what part of your logic is causing the problem.

Comment: dthree, in my logic i am sending the callback to my object and that object is invoking it.

Comment: Hmm. Could it be invoking it twice? This could cause that error.

Comment: No it's invoking only once, but if I do not call callback my process is existing without any error.

Comment: 1. You've done a triple check that the callback isn't called twice? Perhaps put a log statement before the callback to be sure? 2. Do you do any other type of REPL manipulation in your logic, i.e. messing with `stdin` or `stdout`, or using Node's `repl` module, etc.? This can create conflicts which usually causes the above type of error.